# Remote login error: "DISPLAY is not set"

Tags: imac, display, login

**How to set up X's to be able login on your iMac remotely and run graphical applications?**

When I login I get this:

```
servername:~ loginname$ xterm
xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: 
xterm: DISPLAY is not set
servername:~ loginname$ echo $DISPLAY

servername:~ loginname$  launchctl list | grep xquartz 
-   0   org.macosforge.xquartz.X11.5840
5342    -   org.macosforge.xquartz.startx
```

P.S. I installed XQuartz 2.7.5 (xorg-server 1.14.4) and use it successfully from iMac itself for many mouths already.
I have OSX 10.9.4.

Comment: How did you login to the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution appeared to be straight forward: just set

```
export DISPLAY=":0"
```

in `.bashrc` or whatever file your shell sources its profile from.

Comment: I would add that this is correct, but you'll need XQuartz installed on the machine you're using to remote into your iMac. You'll also be limited to X11 applications, not regular apps. Use VNC for regular apps.

Comment: @Alex, you have to have a lot of software installed and setuped properly on machine you login from, starting from operation system itself:). I do not see why I should put all these stuff in the answer. P.S. I logged in from linux machine, so XQuartz is not relevant here.

Comment: OS and other software isn't pertinent to this question. Running X software remotely does require the Xserver on your local machine (linux box), not the remote one (iMac). You don't need XQuartz here at all then for remote purposes. Your question doesn't give any information about the linux box, or even that it is a linux host, so the comment is relevant.